# how to make group an drag in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a plane and sphere, texture cube and simple cube and a loaded amf on it, how can I drag or pan the plane, and drag all the mentioned object togethor, actually I made group, and I helped from trackBallControl and OrbitControl.
here are parts of my code, I don't know really what to do for it. I can drag seperately but not as a group.

```
var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(50, 50, 0xffffff, 0x555555);
        grid.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), 90 * (Math.PI / 180));
        scene.add(grid);
var grids= [grid];
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
controls.panSpeed = 10;
controls.noZoom = false;
controls.noPan = false;
controls.staticMoving = true;
controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;
var dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(grids, camera, renderer.domElement);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
controls.enabled = false;
        });

dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
controls.enabled = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right. You can add all the stuff (*a plane and sphere, texture cube and simple cube and a loaded amf*) as children of the `grid` (which is `THREE.GridHelper()`):

```
var objects = [];

var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
scene.add(grid);
objects.push(grid); // add to the array for DragControls

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(...);
sphere.position.set(-1, 1, 0);
grid.add(sphere); // as a child of the grid

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(...);
cube.position.set(1, 1, 0);
grid.add(cube); // as a child of the grid

var dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement);
dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
  controls.enabled = false;
});
dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function(event) {
  controls.enabled = true;
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/sj4p7b0k/) example. Please clarify, if I missed something from your question.

Comment: that's it, Thank u a lot. it helped me , but still the amf loader hasn't been accepted as a chiled. @prisoner849